# show or copy password instead of dots in application

Tags: restore, password

In windows i had a program to inspect the password that i stored in filezilla.
But I forgot my ftp password I can still see the dots but I want to see what the password was that I stored.

Is there anything like that for the mac?

I found a solution for filezilla.

In the filezilla menu use "file->Export".
Save the file to a location

An XML file is generated with al the ftp sites entry's

Open the file with a browser and you should be able to see the passwords

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course. Try finding your "Keychain"-program,which is in the Utilities folder within the Applications folder.
After entering you admin pass, you can view all the passwords stored by your Mac. WiFi passwords, website-logins,...

Comment: hmm that's handy! I can find back my wifi pass :) but not able to find the passwords in my filezilla yet. any idea under which category i should look?

Comment: Normally they are stored as "Internet Access Passwords". Try to search for the ftp or site you are trying to access from Filezilla.

Comment: looked under all category's and keychains searched under username and ftp server name ( ftp.myserver.com ) there doesn't seams to be an entry of filezilla

Comment: And are you sure the passwords are filled in automatically when you connect using Filezilla?

Comment: Jep I have filled them in in my 'site manager' i can connect to my ftp servers just by clicking and passwords are set and needed for a ftp connection. I think they are not stored in the keychain